# Change channel permissions in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to make a simple channel lock function in DiscordJS but I ran into a problem while trying to do so.

The problem is probably in `message.channel.overwritePermissions`

[Here](https://ctrlv.link/eAAN) is the error

```js
if (message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) {
  let roles = message.guild.roles;
  let allRole = roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '902820481110011934');
  message.channel.overwritePermissions({
    SEND_MESSAGES: true
  });
} else {
  message.channel.send("You don't have permission to do this!");
}
```

Comment: Which version of discord.js you're using?

Answer (score 2):

[`GuildChannel.overwritePermissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) accepts only an **array** or **collection** of [`OverwriteResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/typedef/OverwriteResolvable). `OverwriteResolvable` can be [`OverwriteData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/typedef/OverwriteData). The id is required. This is the way to set overwrites in v12

```js
message.channel.overwritePermissions({
  id: "role_or_user_id",
  allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES"]
})
```